# Conditional Replacement of Variables in a Matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, conditional-statements

Currently I'm achieving this like so:

```
b = a;
b(b > 0) = 1;
b(b < 0) = -1;
```

This works but seems inelegant to me. Surely there is a better way of doing this? A one liner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b=sign(a);`  for example?

This should do the same.

Answer (score 2):

Ander's answer is the one I would go with here.  Here's another one as a mental exercise.  You can achieve the same using `logical` operators:

```
b = (a > 0) - (a < 0);
```

The elegance of the above expression is such that for any value of `a` except at 0, only one part of the equation is "on" at any given time.  If any value of `a` is positive, then the output will be `logical` `true` as the left side of the equation activates while the right side does not.  Similarly, if any value of `a` is negative, the right side of the equation activates and also evaluates to `true` while the left side does not.  There is a negative sign assigned to the right-hand side and so this coalesces to -1.  This in combination with the left-hand side all coalesces to a `double` precision array thus completes our output.  It is also prudent to examine what the expression gives you when any value of `a` is equal to 0.  Since neither of the expressions will activate, this evaluates to `logical` `false` for both expressions, and `false - false` coalesces to 0 which is the result we desire.

## Example

```
>> a = -2:0.5:2

a =

   -2.0000   -1.5000   -1.0000   -0.5000         0    0.5000    1.0000    1.5000    2.0000

>> b = (a > 0) - (a < 0)

b =

    -1    -1    -1    -1     0     1     1     1     1
```